# VBA TreeView_NodeCheck: Search for Match in Column and post in row beneath if empty

Tags: vba, treeview, nodes

I am trying to work around the tough task to save selected nodes from a TreeView (tough due to my limited VBA knowledge) by first saving a UserID with a TextBox_AfterUpdate Event and subsequently saving the checked node's full path in the rows below when a match is found. Multiple checks are possible, that's why I approached it the way I did below.

I am working on this Problem for 2 working-days now and pray that one of you can help me out of my misery here haha
No Error is produced and a look at the Debugger Shows me that each column in found correctly. Also, the saving user ID via TextBox_AfterUpdate Event works like a treat and should stay this way. It simply does not copy it - please Help.

Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub SuppNo_AfterUpdate()
'########Save SuppNo for CG-entry-saving########
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")

    Dim lastcol As Long

    With ws
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    'Copy Supplier No into Row 1 and next empty column

    ws.Cells(1, lastcol).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.SuppNo.Value
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub CGTreeView_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")
    Dim myNode As Node

    '1. - - Copy Supplier No into Row 1 and next empty column
    'Done in SuppNo_Change event


    '2.1. - - Find matching entry
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim colName, NodePath As String

    strFind = Me.SuppNo
    NodePath = Me.CGTreeView.SelectedItem.FullPath


    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=Me.SuppNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '2.2. - - Find the last empty row and copy each new FullPath when checked
            For i = 2 To 50
                If Cells(i, col) Is Nothing Then
                    ws.Cells(i, col) = NodePath
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next i

            '~~> If not found
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I added a few features to eliminate duplicates.

```
Private Sub SuppNo_AfterUpdate()
'########Save SuppNo for CG-entry-saving########
    Dim IDColumn As Long
    Dim dItems As Object
    Dim c As Range, ItemsRange As Range
    Dim n As Node

    Set dItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")
        IDColumn = getSuppNoColumn
        .Cells(1, IDColumn).Value = Me.SuppNo.Value
        Set ItemsRange = .Range(.Cells(2, IDColumn), .Cells(.Rows.count, IDColumn).End(xlUp))
        If Not ItemsRange Is Nothing Then

            For Each c In ItemsRange
                dItems(c.text) = vbNullString
            Next

        End If

    End With

    For Each n In CGTreeView.Nodes
        n.Checked = dItems.exists(n.FullPath)
    Next
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub CGTreeView_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    Dim IDColumn As Long
    Dim dItems As Object
    Dim n As Node

    If Me.SuppNo.Value <> "" Then
        IDColumn = getSuppNoColumn
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")

            .Range(.Cells(1, IDColumn), .Cells(.Rows.count, IDColumn).End(xlUp)).Offset(1).Clear

            Set dItems = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

            For Each n In CGTreeView.Nodes
                If n.Checked Then dItems(n.FullPath) = vbNullString
            Next

            If dItems.count > 0 Then .Cells(2, IDColumn).Resize(dItems.count) = Application.Transpose(dItems.Keys)

        End With

    End If
End Sub

Function getSuppNoColumn() As Long
    Dim f As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")
        Set f = .Range("1:1").Find(What:=Me.SuppNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            getSuppNoColumn = IIf(.Cells(1, 1) = "", 1, .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column)
        Else
            getSuppNoColumn = f.Column
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thomas, what would I Need to Change so that, if only the Commodity Group is ticked in the TreeView, it is saved with a "\" afterwards? I encounter problems populating the TreeView because having, for instance, only "Handelsware" without a \ is not recognized when I try to split the strings later to populate the TreeView in the "Search and Edit" Tab.

Comment: ` dItems(n.FullPath) =` would need to be changed to ` dItems(n.FullPath & "\") =`